# How to increase memory for debugging of Developer options

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I would like to know how to increase memory for debugging of Developer options without DDMS connection. Please kindly advice me.

Background: I have a problem with my smartphones sometimes does not work well when to use application out side of my house without my PC. So, I would like to keep logs as much as possible. I would like to keep them for a day at least.

Answer (score 0):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8625139/967945) on our sister site for programming questions, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com.)

Comment: Thank you, Looks does not support to enhance the cache size of log on the smartphone yet